# Keep part of matched string when replacing with RegEx in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have about 1,000 lines of html that look like this:

```
<input type="text" readonly value="some-value-here" class="unit size1of2" />
```

I am able to find all of those lines using the RegEx search of

```
<input type="text" readonly value="[^<]+" class="unit size1of2" />
```

However, I am trying to change all of them to

```
<input type="hidden" value="same-value-that-was-found" />
```

Any ideas on what I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: `<input type="text" readonly value="([^<]+)" class="unit size1of2" />` --> `<input type="hidden" value="$1" />`

Comment: Ahh thank you for this! The parentheses were what I was missing!